# WordPress Woocommerce custom media grid with links

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, grid, media

I'm trying to add an eye-catching grid to the homepage of my webshop.
I use WordPress - Woocommerce for the shop with the [Shopkeeper theme](https://themeforest.net/item/shopkeeper-ecommerce-wp-theme-for-woocommerce/9553045).

I want a grid with different sizes of pictures. I would like to be able to click on a picture and navigate to a specific product category. (see example below)

[image: Custom grid example]

I already tried to use the 'Product Categories' grid, which seemed to be what I want in the first place. But you can only have 1 item in that grid for every Product Category.

What would be the easiest way to become this sort of grid?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple answer to that. This would require editing the code and playing with CSS. You should contact the support team of the theme as this isn't specific to Wordpress itself but to the theme.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely contact them directly.